# php when a class is instantiated are all functions then loaded?

Tags: php, oop

When you instantiate a class does the php interpreter read/load the entire class? Or does it only read/load the functions as and when you call each function?

Comment: The entire file is loaded and parsed prior to execution. Do you have a specific design decision to make? Maybe it's worth elaborating

Comment: Methods (classes' functions) do nothing when the class is initialized. They're only parsed for correctness (as in *typos*), but the work is only done when you call them.

Comment: It reads an entire class when the class _definition_ is loaded. It does not load functionality seperately when called or instantiated, it's just an object of an entirely already known class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your class can be instantiated, it must be loaded and parsed first; during the parsing phase, all the class methods are converted into [opcodes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.php) and stored using their name.

When a class is instantiated, its method block points to the class structure that was parsed earlier.

So to answer your question: yes, it reads and parses the functions but obviously only runs the function body when they're called.